# Show wordpress post thumbnail with SQL query interacting with wp_post, wp_term_relationships and wp_terms

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have this query that when I execute it, it pulls 3 single posts, which I chose based on their id. The only thing that doesn't get pulled is the post thumbnail. I've tried intercepting with post_meta joining with post_id etc, but no success at all

Here's what I got until now

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
#LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
#LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON (pm.meta_value = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL)
#LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata'
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE p.ID in ('800','808', '569') 
  AND p.post_type in ('post', 'attachment')
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
```

The ones with hash-tags are my failed attempt, I get null value on meta_key column